# Will my PSU be powerful enough if I upgraded my Video Card?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power

My current specs are:

- Thermal Take TR2-470NP 470W
- Asus M2N-X
- AMD Athlon64x2 4200+ (Windsor)
- 2x1GB 667 DDR2
- A bunch of HDDs (1 IDE, 3 SATA)
- 7600GT

If I am calculating it right, my current power consumption must be around:

```
35W + 90W + 15W + 4 * 15W + 60W = 260W
```

I am willing to upgrade my VC to HD5770 and from what I've read, it uses 18-108W, i.e. I'll need to add just another 50W, making it to 310W.

What do you think? Will the PSU be powerful enough? At the moment, it's giving me 12.74V on the 12V rail (or whatever it's called). Not that I'm sure it's saying anything as I rather think one should be probing the amperes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That power supply unit is a VERY bad unit. Not only is it unable to produce its maximum rated wattage (shuts off/and or explodes around 400W), it is horribly inefficient and doesn't even have active power factor correction! It also provides shaky power to your components which makes them more prone to failure and less overclocking headroom.

Voltage is not a good indicator of PSU health, especially when you are measuring it through software.

I would replace that power supply ASAP; a new and more efficient unit will easily pay for itself in reduced electricity bills.

Good units are (they could all power the rig):

- Corsair CX430 - amazing for the price
- Antec EA380/430
- Antec NeoEco 400W
- Seasonic 350/400W bronze

My vote goes to the CX430 for its really low price.

Comment: +1. I would just point out that going to 500 or ever 600W may be worth it; power supplies tend to run quieter, cooler, and last a lot longer when they're under their rated load.

Comment: You sound as though you had first hand experience with my PSU? Is it the case?

Comment: This is a myth. While powersupplies are more efficient at 50% load than at 100%, because bigger power supplies use more power at idle (which is what your computer does most of the time) it actually costs you more.

Comment: OK guys, I'll bear that in mind. So, I'll have to save up for a PSU first. And yes, CX430 is quite well-priced.

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore 
I have had experience with it's younger brother, the TR2-430W. Read any review of either unit by a reputable tester and you'll see they are absolute garbage (as with most of the stuff thermaltake produces)

Here is a nice review: http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Thermaltake-Purepower-430W-NP-Power-Supply-Review/332

Comment: Um, you're getting me confused now. :-D

Comment: I've deleted my comment and voted this up.

Comment: Basically, if you get a PSU that has too many watts, it actually uses more electricity than if you got a smaller one. 

More info here: http://www.overclock.net/power-supplies/872013-50-load-myth.html

Comment: Thanks for the article. Too bad I was too stupid to buy a TT PSU. :-|

Comment: @charliehorse55 after reading [that article](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Thermaltake-Purepower-430W-NP-Power-Supply-Review/332/7) I've noticed a few differences between my 470NP and the 430W NP. One of which is mine's got two 12+ rails, one rated at 14A, and the other at 15A.

Comment: PSU rails have nothing to do with it's performance. They are a safety feature. The internals are most likely very similar inside. 

A rail is just a current monitor - if the current goes over that amount it shuts off the unit.